# How to reference a planning type in a plan

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I have a custom odoo module, which extends some existing modules like hr. I want to create an onboarding plan with several predefined tasks in it.

This is my plan acitivity type xml which works at it should. If I update the applikation with this file, I get the desired tasks in the planning types overview.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <record id="hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract" model="hr.plan.activity.type">
        <field name="activity_type_id" ref="mail.mail_activity_data_todo"/>
        <field name="responsible">manager</field>
        <field name="summary">Create work contract</field>
        <field name="note">Create the work contract for the employee.</field>
    </record>

    <record id="hr_plan_activity_type_employee_model_in_erp" model="hr.plan.activity.type">
        <field name="activity_type_id" ref="mail.mail_activity_data_todo"/>
        <field name="responsible">manager</field>
        <field name="summary">Employee model in ERP</field>
        <field name="note">Complete the employee model in ERP (AHV, Banking, etc.)</field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

This is my plan.xml which should create a plan with the activity types. The creation of the plan works, but if I reference the activity types, I'll get an error message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <!-- Onboarding -->

    <record id="hr_plan_onboarding" model="hr.plan">
        <field name="name">Onboarding</field>
        
    <field name="plan_activity_type_ids"
           eval="[(6,0,[ref('mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_employee_model_in_erp')])]"/>

    <field name="plan_activity_type_ids"
           eval="[(4,0,[ref('mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract')])]"/>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

In the manifest.py file I first load the plan.activity.type.xml and then the plan.xml so this shouldn't be a problem.

This is the error message I get when I try to upgrade my customized module mycompany:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0e\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_model.py", line 1670, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: hr.plan.activity.type.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract" while parsing file:/c:/users/myuser/appdata/local/openerp%20s.a/odoo/addons/13.0/mycompany/data/hr/plan.xml:2, near
<odoo>

    <!-- Onboarding -->

    <record id="hr_plan_onboarding" model="hr.plan">
        <field name="name">Onboarding</field>
        <field name="plan_activity_type_ids" ref="hr.plan.activity.type.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract"/>
    </record>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String identifier stored in `ir.model.data`, can be used to refer to a record regardless of its database identifier during data imports or `export/import` roundtrips.

External identifiers are in the form `module.id` (e.g. `account.invoice_graph`). From within a module, the module. prefix can be left out.

Sometimes referred to as `xml id` or `xml_id` as XML-based Data Files make extensive use of them.

In your example you used `model_name.id` which probably does not exist in the database, to reference  `hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract` record you just need to replace the model name with the module name.

I can see from the log message that the module name is `mycompany`, try to replace the model name with `mycompany`:

```
<record id="hr_plan_onboarding" model="hr.plan">
    <field name="name">Onboarding</field>
    <field name="plan_activity_type_ids" ref="mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract"/>
</record>
```

***Update:`plan_activity_type_ids` is an x2many field***

Use the [special commands](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/models.py#L3436) format to set the x2many field values:

```
<record id="hr_plan_onboarding" model="hr.plan">
    <field name="name">Onboarding</field>
    <field name="plan_activity_type_ids" eval="[(6,0,[ref('mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract')])]"/>
</record>
```

***Edit: Only the first one shows up in the GUI***

To replaces all existing records in the set by the `ids` list (using '(6, 0, ids)') you can provide a list of ids inside the triplet. You can find an example in [res_partner_demo.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/data/res_partner_demo.xml#L44) inside the base module.

***Example:***

```
<field name="plan_activity_type_ids" eval="[(6,0,[ref('mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_employee_model_in_erp'), ref('mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract')])]"/>
```

To add an existing record of id `id` to the set (using `(4, id)`) you need to provide one id for each triplet. You can find an example in [base_groups.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/security/base_groups.xml#L46) inside the base module.

***Example:***

```
<field name="plan_activity_type_ids" eval="[(4,ref('mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_employee_model_in_erp')), (4,ref('mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract'))]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've made progress and get another error now.. Maybe you can help with than one as well?

Comment: raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %s" % (self, value))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Wrong value for hr.plan.plan_activity_type_ids: 16" while parsing file:/c:/users/myuser/appdata/local/openerp%20s.a/odoo/addons/13.0/mycompany/data/hr/plan.xml:2, near
<odoo>

    <!-- Onboarding -->

    <record id="hr_plan_onboarding" model="hr.plan">
        <field name="name">Onboarding</field>
        <field name="plan_activity_type_ids" ref="mycompany.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract"/>
    </record>

Comment: It seems that the value provided to `plan_activity_type_ids` field is wrong, It is valid for a many2one field. To manipulate the set of records stored in/associated with the x2many fields, check my edit

Comment: Hi sry to bother you again. I added more activities to the hr plan and only the first one shows up in the gui. I tried putting every activity in the plan in a own record, but this didn't work either. You seem to know your way around odoo and I din't find any solutions on the support page.

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you added those activities.

Comment: Sure, I just edited the plan.xml file in the question!

Comment: You have declared the `plan_activity_type_ids` twice and the second item when using `4` command should be the record id and you need to provide one id for each triplet.Check my edit and feel free to comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Your ref ids are wrong. `hr.plan.activity.type.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract`  is wrong. You get only one `.` in a reference. its `[<module_name>.]ext_id_of_object`.

If you reference the object from the same module you don't have to use module name.part

If you can see the database tables. then things you are referencing are in table `ir_model_data`

So if the thing you are referencing is in your own model then you cant use just `hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract` as a reference or `your_model_name.hr_plan_activity_type_create_work_contract`